# How do I check if a MongoClient object has write access to database?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have established a connection to a Mongo DB:

```
var database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
```

How do I find out if database.Client has write access to the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you have appropriate permissions, [administrative commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/#view-a-user-s-roles) exist to return the list of roles for the user and permissions for the role. From there you should be able to figure out whether the user has "write access" to a particular database.

I use the quotes around "write access" because the permissions defined by MongoDB are more complicated than that.

If you don't have administrative access to view users and roles, you'd need to perform an action to find out whether you are allowed to perform it. I.e., you'd need to actually try writing something.